# Dymola, whitespace and version control

Tags: tortoisesvn, whitespace, line-breaks, modelica, dymola

I opened a Modelica library in Dymola, changed one line, closed Dymola and clicked "Save all", now TortoiseSVN is showing several hundred changed files instead of just one file with the one line changed I intended to do. All these changes are either whitespace, or line breaks, introduced by Dymola it seems.

Of course I can now be careful to only commit the file I have changed (and revert the rest), but that makes committing more time-consuming and error-prone than it needs to be. Or I can just commit it all, but that makes it hard for my colleagues to review the change. Also, it feels like it is not deterministic, so a later commit might just revert parts back. I sometimes even revert all changes, then use a text editor to change just the one line. All this makes version control unnecessarily complicated.

When I look at the commits and diffs for e.g. the Modelica Standard library:
https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/commits/master
The diffs are nice and small and readable usually. Is there a trick to avoid the whitespace issue?
How I can I turn off all autoformatting by Dymola? Is there a technical reason to do it in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things you can do to make pretty git commits for Modelica code:

1. Use a text editor instead of a graphical editor. You have absolute control of what you change.
2. Use a graphical editor that does not change whitespace. I'm not sure of other alternatives, but OpenModelica/OMEdit will preserve existing indentation as much as possible (it can also be used to minimize diffs from changes in other tools, but it works less and less well the more changes there are).
3. Use a formatter as a pre-commit hook (indenting all files according to some settings in the formatter; but then you can't manually change whitespace).
4. Hope someone on stackoverflow has more alternatives than this.

Comment: "OMEdit will preserve [...] as much as possible" - this sounds like it is a relly tricky thing to achieve - but why? For a normal text editor, this is the normal way of working!?

Comment: Seems this paper gives more details: https://www.modelica.org/events/modelica2008/Proceedings/sessions/session6a3.pdf

Comment: The approach OpenModelica now uses is different and easier than that paper. It's difficult to have an API to manipulate the program and preserve all information. The current approach compares 2 concrete syntax trees and preserves all subtrees that are identical, which results in only changed subtrees potentially changing formatting.

Comment: Basic question probably: How large is one "subtree", is it one class or smaller? Few lines? One package?

Comment: It's going to be an entire package, a component, an expression, or annotation. It's quite fine-grained, and ignoring large parts of the file if there are no changes in it.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.3384/ecp21181529

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce (but not entirely prevent) this behavior as follows:

1. Increase the maximum line length, e.g. to 130

   - In the GUI: Options > Text Editor > Max line length
   - From the command line: Advanced.MaxLineLength=130
2. Let Dymola format your whole library one time

   - Open the text view of the top-level package
   - Mark everything with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
   - Auto-format with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or Right-Click > Auto-Format
   - Save everything with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   - Now go through the changes. Most will be useful, but sometimes spaces are removed, which you usually like to keep (especially before `import` and `extends` statements. They are sometimes moved to the very left)
   - Commit the changes
3. From now on try to save individual models only, not packages
   (When packages are saved, Dymola sometimes reformats the nested classes)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It would still be a great improvement for anyone working with SVN or git to improve the Dymola default here. The OMedit approach outlined by sjoelund.se seems to be a very good starting point, this would at least limit white space changes to files where I actually changed anything, so instead of 300 files I only have to check 3 files.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the Dymola 2020x or later as this behavior has been reduced in these.

Comment: @user2024223, Any detailed release notes on this topic?

Comment: One workaround is to use Notepad to change package.mo files, to avoid whitespace changes in files that have not been edited.