# Is there a way to disable auto-formatting code in OpenModelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have created several models manually in OpenModelica using the text editor, most of which are nested inside of packages.  When I am building a model in this way, I will typically keep things aligned for readability.

Sometimes when I am working with the graphical tool, OpenModelica auto-formats the entire file rather than just the section that I am working on.  Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64550959/874701